# Как можно реализовать нестандартные фигуры на css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Нашёл такой макет. Как можно реализовать такие необычные углы??? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем состоит нестандарт, простите? Вы про инпуты? А логически если подумать? берем два дива прямоугольной формы. Справа располагаем `div` и делаем `border-raduis` чтобы он стал круглым. Располагаем его либо абсолютно либо регулируем у всех `z-index`. Ну и последний кружок синий - также `div` с `border-radius` поверх предыдущего круглого.. Что тут нестандартного?... Даже стрелку также можно сделать: один прямоугольный див, один - где идет манипуляция с `border` ... [В дополнение](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/)

Comment: Учитывая фон с паттерном и тени внутри инпутов, все размышления Алексея Шиманского разваливаются как карточный домик. Я бы сделал используя изображения.

Comment: @xaja Ну отчего-же. Я же не дал полное и точное описание. Лишь базу, от которой можно вполне оттолкнуться. А дальше все зависит от скила. У вас его,видимо, нет, вот отсюда и выводы. Понятно, что картинками легче, это факт. Но то, что реализовано на картинке, вполне можно сделать на голом `css`. Теже тени внутри инпутов - доп. дивы с бордерами и т.д.. Другой вопрос - стоит ли игра свеч.

Comment: Ответ: не стоит.

Answer (score 4):

Приблизительно так

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/qxut01kj/)

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
form {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    position: relative;
}
form .input-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
form .input-wrap:nth-of-type(1):before, form .input-wrap:nth-of-type(2):before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
form .input-wrap:nth-of-type(1):before {
    top: 10px;
}
form .input-wrap:nth-of-type(2):before {
    bottom: 10px;
}
input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type="text"] {
    height: 45px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f00;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input type="text" placeholder="field 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input type="text" placeholder="field 2" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Comment: ну конечно, а теперь давайте добавим фон с паттерном

Comment: добавил http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/x11hrkox/ и что не так?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x11hrkox/1/ яж говорю - с паттерном.